# How to get data from two table in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am unable to getting data from two table in android using left join.

Here is the my query:

```
public Cursor getrespondentDataNew(String loc_id) {
        Cursor cur = null;

final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r INNER JOIN respondentType rt ON r.type_code = rt.rtype_code WHERE r.site_code='" + loc_id + "'";

        cur = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
 Log.i("sql:", "SQL Test=" + MY_QUERY);
 Log.i("cur:", "cur Test=" + cur.getCount());
```

and

```
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r INNER JOIN respondentType rt ON r.type_code = rt.rtype_code WHERE r.site_code=?";
cur = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{loc_id});
```

....

```
04-04 11:45:28.212: I/sql:(11017): SQL Test=SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r,respondentType rt where r.type_code = rt.rtype_code and r.site_code='4'
04-04 11:45:28.224: I/cur:(11017): cur Test=0
```

**EDIT**: If i run this Query: why i am getting last value of rt.rtype_name:

```
SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r,respondentType rt where r.type_code = rt.rtype_code   or r.site_code='4' group by  r.code
```

In both case i did not get value, what is the wrong with this query.

My tables:

**respondentTable** 
[image]

**respondentType**

[image]

I am testing site_code 4.

Comment: Does your database really contain a `site_code` with a value that is the string `4`? How do you know that the value in the database isn't a number?

Comment: yes, I have defined site_code is string.

Comment: SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); the declared data type of the column does not matter. What is the data type of the value?

Comment: site_code is TEXT type.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(site_code) FROM respondentTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it another way by following query style,

```
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r,respondentType rt where r.type_code = rt.rtype_code and r.site_code='" + loc_id + "'";
```

Comment: Not possible, can you please tell me the data type of your site_code column ?

Comment: it is string type means text.

Comment: where is `type_code' column in `respondentTable` table ?? I guess you should match both table's ID . Please try my updated answer.

Comment: type_code is not in snapshot in above my question, but here type_code value is empty.

Comment: Well then as per the query, there should be some matching value in that field. Can you paste the snapshot of another half database in question ?

Comment: well you should have value in that field, try inserting 3 or 5 or just remove `r.type_code = rt.rtype_code and` from my answer and try execute it again.

Comment: I have still problem. Here if i run this query; SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r,respondentType rt where r.type_code = rt.rtype_code   or r.site_code='4' group by  r.code   then i am getting value but rt.rtype_code is getting last value. why this? i am still confused. Here in r.type_code value is empty where rt.rtype_code have. accorading to r.type_code ,i want to get rt.rtype_code.

Comment: can you send me the  database file by email ?

Comment: bro can you help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611870/fetch-records-from-sqlite-database-based-on-query

Answer (score 0):

I Solve Problem using **left outer join.**

```
SELECT r.name, r.site_name, r.age, r.gender, rt.rtype_name, r.parent_code, r.code, r.site_code, r.interview_date FROM respondentTable r LEFT OUTER JOIN respondentType rt ON r.type_code = rt.rtype_code    where r.site_code='4'
```