# Fetch Records from SQLite Database based on Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using following query to `fetch` data from **SQLite** database, where `sent = 0` in *pending* table

But, the issue is I am getting all the `records`, even where **sent = 1**

Whereas, I am `trying` to get only records those *sent* status is **0**

```
String sql = "SELECT ec.visit_date, ec.mobile_id, p.mobile_id, p.sent from ectrack ec LEFT OUTER JOIN pending p WHERE ec.mobile_id = p.mobile_id and p.sent = 0";
```

**UPDATED : 1**

I have tried with **INNER JOIN** as well, but *getting all the records*, not only those where `sent = 0` please check where I am doing mistake ?

```
String str = "SELECT ec.visit_date, ec.mobile_id, p.mobile_id, p.sent from ectrack ec INNER JOIN pending p ON ec.mobile_id=p.mobile_id WHERE p.sent=0";
```

**UPDATED : 2**

I have tried below query to *fetch data* from `pending` table only where **sent = 0** and getting records those status is *sent = 0* not each and every record

```
String sql = "select * from pending where sent = 0";
```

But, I have to fetch data from **ectrack** table too, like you can see in my first query...

I have to fetch data from **ectrack** table based on *sent* status available in **pending** table.

Comment: You really should learn some SQL basics ... in this case: how JOIN works, differents between INNER and OUTER ...

Comment: You can use inner join here.

Comment: Can you show us the full table definitions AND put some line breaks in the SQL?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding single quotes around the value you are looking for. For instance: `...WHERE p.sent = '0'";`

Comment: That's not necessarily true. If "sent" is a numeric value, that won't help.